# How to read "OR call stack" in Android Developer Console crash report?

Tags: android, crash-reports

When logging in to Android Developer Console one can access the crash reports. **Since I uploaded the mapping files, the logs are NOT obfuscated** but still I am not sure how to read them:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
    at com.my.app.Path.To.Package.CrashClass.methodA(TheClass.java)
    or                     .methodX (TheClass.java)
    or                     .methodY (TheClass.java)
    or                     .methodY (TheClass.java)
    at com.my.app.Path.To.Package.CallingClass$7.run (CallingClass.java) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6692) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

I do not understand what the information about `methodA`, **or** `methodB`, etc...

Does this mean, is that a `NullPointerException` happen in each of these classes?

Is this the call stack within the `CrashClass` (would be surprising sice `methodX` does not call `methodA` or vice versa)?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to another question pointed me to the right solution for this question:

ProGuard can map different methods of a class to the same obfuscated name. For example the two methods `MyClass.method1(...)` and `MyClass.method2(...)` could both be mapped to the obfuscated name `MyClass.a(...)`.

Thus when an error occurs in method `a` on only knows, that this happened in `method1` **OR** `method2`. This is why the call stack may contain the or-items...

To avoid this problem one can add the following option to the Proguard configuration:

```
-useuniqueclassmembernames
```

More information can be found [here](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage#useuniqueclassmembernames).